# SQL Performance: Filter first or Join first

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, inner-query

I am having three tables viz., Employees, Department and Grievance. The Employees table has over a million records. I need to find the details of the employee, his/her department and grievances raised by him/her.

I could think of the below two queries to find the result:

**1. Filtering the records first to get only the records of the employee whose data is required:**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID= @EmployeeID) Emp    
LEFT JOIN Department Dpt ON Emp.EmployeeID= Dpt.EmployeeID    
LEFT JOIN Grievance Grv ON Emp.EmployeeID= Grv.EmployeeID;
```

**2. Join first:**

```
SELECT * FROM Employees Emp    
    LEFT JOIN Department Dpt ON Emp.EmployeeID= Dpt.EmployeeID    
    LEFT JOIN Grievance Grv ON Emp.EmployeeID= Grv.EmployeeID    
WHERE EmployeeID= @EmployeeID);
```

If we consider the SQL logical processing order which starts with FROM>INNER JOIN>OUTER JOIN>WHERE>....SELECT, the first query should perform better/fast as there will be only one record from the Inner Query and will be joined with the further tables.
However, on executing both the queries I do not find any performance difference and both queries takes almost same time.

Could you please check and let me know where I am thinking wrong?

Comment: can you use the 'actual execution plan' ? [Ctrl + M] before running the queries ?

Comment: If you look at the execution plans, you should be able to see how the data is fetched for both queries.

Comment: See estimate/actual plan. SQL immediately throw a predicate  value to the table Employees

Comment: The SQL language is declarative rather than procedural so you are describing the desired results rather than instructing SQL Server how to process the query. The optimizer may refactor semantically identical queries as to return results in the most efficient way.

Comment: Work on your indexes and Statistics - these are the key to performance for large tables

Comment: Hi. What did you learn from googling & otherwise researching sql/database/dbms query optimization? How is that inapplicable to your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry about it.  The processing of the query occurs in three phases:

1. Parsing
2. Compilation
3. Execution

A key part of the compilation phase is optimization.  This is when the SQL engine determines the optimal execution plan.

In your first query, SQL Server is going to ignore the subquery.  The two queries should have the same execution plan.

Note:  This is not true in all databases.  Some simpler databases actually materialize the subquery.

From an aesthetic perspective, I prefer the second query -- just to avoid an unnecessary subquery and so all the filtering is in the outer `where` clause (where it is expected).

Answer (score 1):

Your general premise is the wrong approach for SQL.

Write the query first and let your DB work out the plan. Optimize only if you find a problem, otherwise you're generally able to find a better use of your time.

The query plan will tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "logical processing order", unless you mean "evaluating the query 1:1 with subexpressions", but that's irrelevant since the DBMS doesn't do that. Your wrong thinking is in thinking you have a reasonable mental model of the DBMS execution. Read about SQL as declarative. And about query execution/implementation--entire books await. Just be straightforward in design & querying and learn about indexing & plans and your DBMS's basic optimization model/strategy.

[Which query is more performant?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46725056/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter the order of tables you've used.
Unless you use query hint (FORCE ORDER), which I'd not recommend. 
Anyway, you are taking away a chance to optimize execution plan of SQL Server by using a star (*). Use only columns you really need. Do rebuild statistics to make sure SQL Server has enough information to build an optimal execution plan.